# A similarity metric for sets

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning

Consider two sets with non-negative entries $\mathcal{S}=\{s_1,s_2,\cdots,s_N\}$ and $\mathcal{P}=\{p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_N\}$ , and consider an index set $\mathcal{T}$ of cardinality $K \leq N$ that contains indices of $K$ largest entries of set $P$. Then, let us define an asymmetric similarity metric

$D_{\mathcal{S}\rightarrow\mathcal{P}}=\frac{\sum_{t\in\mathcal{T}} \mathcal{S}(t)}{\sum_{t\in\mathcal{T}}\mathcal{P}(t)}$

It is clear that $0 \leq D_{\mathcal{S}\rightarrow\mathcal{P}}\leq 1$. But I haven't seen something similar in distance/similarity metrics literature, e.g.,

"Comprehensive Survey on Distance/Similarity Measures between Probability Density Functions"

I wonder if someone has seen something similar in academic literature? Thanks.

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^N s(i)=1$, and $\sum_{i=1}^N p(i)=1$

Comment: It is not clear that $D \le 1$. In fact, it is easy to come up with counter-examples, such as $K = 1, \mathcal P = \{0.4, 0.6\}, \mathcal S = \{0.1, 0.9\}$. Then $D = 1.5$.

Comment: Thank you Paul for your comment. It is helpful. Please excuse my oversight.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was your oversight, or I was misunderstanding something, but I'm glad it was helpful to you.